# How to change background color of line highlighting during debug process in Netbeans?

Tags: debugging, netbeans, colors, xdebug

how to change background color of line highlighting during debug process in Netbeans?

[image: image of debug hilighting in NetBeans on a dark background]

Tried to change "Highlight Caret Row". No success. It only changes bg color of line where cursor blinks, but not debugging line:

[image: image of an attempt to change the color of "Highlight Caret Row"]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## `Annotations` Tab

Try the "Fonts & Colors" > "Annotions" tab.

Restart NetBeans (or re-open editors) for changes to take effect.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: @heron First you need to close and reopen the editor (or restart Netbeans). Second you need to find the exact annotation. The symbol next to the annotation always match the editor's icon, so just find all the matches and change the colour. Then close and reopen the file and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Open Tools->Options->Fonts&Colors then go to "Annotations" tab.
Color options for debug line in "Current Program Counter" item. 
It is works for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is a breakpoint selection in the Annotations tab.

Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Annotations Tab -> Breakpoint

Change the background color of this.

Edit:
Change all of the Current Program Counter categories too, all of them will be run into in various scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You must restart Netbeans to changes takes effects

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see highlighted lines, it's possible that the project settings aren't configured correctly.

E.g. when using a htaccess redirect from the root folder to folder myapplication, be sure to edit Project->Properties->Sources->Web Root to the redirect folder.

That solved the issue for me.