# How do I change highlighting on a dark L & F

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-9

Netbeans 9.0
Win10-64 & Win7-64

I've set my background to black - I forget the motif name and I can't find out how change it again. Java highlighting of same objects (methods, object names, etc.) is all but unreadable. I've tried to find a place to change it (Tools->Options->Fonts & Colors->Highlighting) and can't find the right highlighting option. Ditto for breakpoint highlighting.

And in addition, the cursor can not be seen. Probably the cursor color is black and can't be seen on a black background.

For example, click on internalFrame and others are highlighted and unreadable (the first 'internalFrame' is readable, the rest not):

```
JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JINternalFrame();
internalFrame.method1();
internalFrame.method2();
```

Is there a way to change these highlights?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change these highlights?

Yes, but you have to go to different places to change them, depending on what you want to change:

(1) To change most coloring for the edit window containing program source:

- **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors**
- Select the **Syntax** tab, and then select *Java* (or whatever language you are using) from the **Language** drop list.
- Most of the options you want to modify are probably listed in the **Category** window.
- Beneath the **Category** window is a **Preview** window which will immediately show you the effect of changing the **Foreground** and/or **Background** colors for a given **Category** entry. As an (extreme) example, this screen shot shows the effect of changing the font color to yellow and the background color to red for Java identifiers:

  [image: fontColor1]
- Some **Category** entries which are not language specific (e.g. *URL*, *Whitespace*) can be found by selecting *All Languages* from the **Language** drop list.
- There is a **Restore** button in the top right of the screen if you mess up, and want to revert to the defaults.

(2) To change the cursor color:

- **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors**
- Select the **Highlighting** tab, and then select *Caret Color* from the **Category** window.
- Select **Foreground** and **Background** colors as appropriate.

(3) To change the highlighting for breakpoint lines see the answers to the SO question [How to change background color of line highlighting during debug process in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9045210/2985643)?

Notes:

- Although you didn't ask, you also have limited ability to change the colors used in the **Console** windows: **Tools > Options > Miscellaneous >** select the **Terminal** tab.
- There are many dark color schemes available for NetBeans, so if the one you are using has annoying limitations just try some of the alternatives. NetBeans 8.2 offers a few under **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins**, such as *Darcula LAF for NetBeans*, *Dark Look And Feel Themes* and *2pmTech L&F*.

  Also, here are a couple of sites that offer many NetBeans themes with previews: https://netbeansthemes.com/ and http://svenspruijt.nl/themebuilder/

Comment: Thanks. I will be trying this shortly.